# How can I integrate existing credentials into an Expo project without using EAS (Expo Application Services)?

Tags: react-native, expo

How can I integrate existing credentials into an Expo project without using EAS (Expo Application Services)? I'm coming from react-native-cli background and have no idea, I can't find a documentation regarding this matter. Really appreciate your help. Thanks